# UBUNTU 14.04 cheese booth not detect webcam

Tags: video, webcam, cheese

Cheese Booth shows an error:

> There was an error playing video from the webcam

[image: Cheese Booth]

I test if webcam works fine or not by opening google hangout, its works fine.

[image: Google Hangout Screenshot]

Please tell, what is the issue in cheese booth.

Note: Sometimes the cheese booth works fine but most of time not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Preferences, and change these resolutions to the lowest.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

2.Now restart cheese.

3.The webcam should work. Keep increasing the resolution until it stops working again.For many webcams, this limit is 640x480.

Comment: Thanks man.. I currently install 16.04 and follow your suggestion. It works fine

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 14.04. Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I can't change the Photo or Video resolutions. I can choose from only one. Even if I use `modprobe` to change the resolution, `cheese` still shows only one and it never changes. Attempted multiple options attempting to get this method to work and I can only surmise that it's due to the fact that I'm using third party applications and hardware with limited capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar problem with cheese so I installed **GTK UVC Video Viewer**. It rich in terms of feature as compared to cheese. You can install it by entering following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I installed guvcview and it didn't work

Comment: It works in a pinch even though it's not the most stable alternative.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Actually, I just found that you need to manually add your user to the audio and video groups. The easiest way is to launch the "users and groups" app and go to manage groups

Original answer:
There seems to be an issue with the permissions on `/dev/video*`.

They are owned by root with no read/write permissions for regular users. My quick-and-dirty hack was a simple:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*
```

Comment: +1 In newer versions there isn't an option for the groups in the settings, but you can edit the groups with `sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER` and `sudo usermod -a -G video $USER`, and then reboot the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you start `cheese` from the terminal you might see this error:

`(cheese:7333): cheese-WARNING **: 09:47:54.438: Device '/dev/video0' is busy: gstv4l2object.c(3706): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Call to S_FMT failed for YUYV @ 160x120: Device or resource busy`

Closing the other app (for me it was a Chrome tab with Google Hangouts) is the work around.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo cheese` if it is a permission problem this will let you open it with the super user privileges.

Comment: When I try above command, it throws an error as  (cheese:2994): cheese-WARNING **: Internal data flow error.: gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin17/GstV4l2Src:video_source:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)