# Error playing video from TeckNet webcam

Tags: video, webcam, streaming

I bought [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000Q3VECE/) TeckNet C016 webcam and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Before buying it, I checked to see if anyone else was using it with Linux and there were positive results.

When I plug the webcam into my PC, I am able to turn a little wheel which activates the LEDs so it's getting power. When it's plugged in, I can see a `video0` entry in `/dev/` (though sometimes it appears as `video1`)

I have Cheese and VLC installed. Starting `cheese` shows the message `There was an error playing video from the webcam`, the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454220/ubuntu-14-04-cheese-booth-not-detect-webcam). I followed the answers for that question. Cheese outputs the following to the console:

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
(cheese:4523): cheese-WARNING **: Internal data flow error.: gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin17/GstV4l2Src:video_source:
```

streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Running as su doesn't help.

I installed `guvcview` which opens 2 windows, of which one disappears before I get a chance to see what it is. I am left with the `guvcviewer controls` window. I assume the other window was to relay the video back to the screen. Among other things, this is printed to the console:

```
checking format: 1196444237
VIDIOC_G_COMP:: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fps is set to 1/25
drawing controls

libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Invalid argument
Checking video mode 640x480@32bpp : OK 
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Invalid argument
```

Finally, I tried VLC and opening a capture device. I set capture mode to `Video Camera`, device to `/dev/video0` and video standard to `All`. I get the following message:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'. Check the log for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

After messing around a bit, I found that `guvcview` will show the video stream when it is plugged in to a USB 2.0 port, instead of the USB 3.0 port I was using before. Cheese will not work, however. I did manage to get a few seconds of video out of it before giving the same error message. VLC also works through USB 2.

Comment: Is it meant to be an answer to the question or an update to the question?