# Lenovo Y50-70 integrated camera not detected (Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5249)

Tags: drivers, lenovo, webcam, realtek

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Y50-70 and the integrated camera is not detected on cheese. When I "lspci" I get this:
"Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5249 (rev 01)".

I tried this: 
[Integrated webcam not detected after update to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04)

This: 
[UBUNTU 14.04 cheese booth not detect webcam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454220/ubuntu-14-04-cheese-booth-not-detect-webcam)

And this: 
[Internal SD card reader not mounted/detected HP realtek rts5227](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492476/internal-sd-card-reader-not-mounted-detected-hp-realtek-rts5227)

None of the above proposed solutions worked for me and I am completely lost on what should I try. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

PS: I am a new Ubuntu user so I am still learning how to swim :)

Comment: Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5249 (rev 01), this is for your Card reader and not webcam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that worked for me. It was a permission problem. I did what "papibe" proposed in post #10 here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189981

> by papibe , November 26th, 2013
>
> It may be a permissions problem: Code:
>
> ```
> ls -l /dev/video0 
> crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 25 19:23 /dev/video0
> ```
>
> Add yourself to the video group: Code:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G video youruser
> ```
>
> replace 'youruser' for your actual username.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but when I restarted the computer, it can't recognize /dev/video0 anymore