# webcam problems - can not save picture

Tags: video, thinkpad, webcam, 22.04, cheese

i have at least 2 issues with my webcam.

first: when i start it up there is no image. setting the resolution then helps as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741242/416663).

what i could not resolve so far it that when i take a picture using `cheese` it can not be encoded and saved. in the terminal i get the error message

> (cheese:1550224): cheese-WARNING **: 09:10:32.703: Output state was
> not configured: ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideoencoder.c(2281):
> gst_video_encoder_can_push_unlocked ():
> /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstEncodeBin:image-encodebin/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0

and the camera input in cheese disappears and is replaced by the message

> There was an error playing video from the webcam

is my install missing a library or what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with Cheese 41.1, that's the version being used in Ubuntu 22.04. It's being worked on, the same has been found to happen in Debian and the issue is already there on [Gnome's gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/cheese/-/issues/133). You can wait some time until it's solved, or use an alternative camera app like Kamoso, or install the Flatpak version that's a bit older and should work fine.

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll keep an eye on that.